# spring boot security + rest не работает

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

Всем привет. Никогда раньше не работал со spring boot и вот решил попробовать сделать простое приложение на spring boot + security + rest + hibernate + postgreSQL.
Загвоздка возникла с доступом к rest адресу регистрации нового пользователя пишет:

```
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/rest/registration/save"
```

Когда отключаю spring security то доступ к адресу осуществляется без проблем.

**POM.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**SpringSecurity.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("IUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService detailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("1234").roles("USER");        auth.userDetailsService(detailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**", "/login/**", "/registration/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin").access("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')");
        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
        http.logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

**RegistrationRestController.java**

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/registration")
public class RegistrationRestController {
    private final UsersService usersService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/save")
    public void registrationNewUser(@RequestBody Users user) {
        usersService.saveNewUser(user);
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder) {
        return springApplicationBuilder.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Весь код не выкладываю поскольку смысла нет от моделей или репозиториев и прочих классов.
Чего может не хватать в приложении для нормального функционирования класса помеченного аннотацией @RestController?

Comment: Не знаю поможет или нет, но `Application extends ...` и override метод нужно убрать

Comment: Пробовал изначально, не помогло

Comment: Без Spring Security точно всё работает? Странно что 404 выдает, если бы хоть 401 ну или 403, то это другое дело

Comment: Не знаю где Вы "отрыли" такой SecurityConfig, но это явно из версии Spring Security 3. Попробуйте убрать `.loginProcessingUrl()`, `.usernameParameter()` и `.passwordParameter()`.

Comment: Да без секьюрити все работает. А изначально конфиг был без этих полей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все решил проблему путем добавления следующей строки `http.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling();` в конфиг файл SecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**", "/login/**", "/registration/**").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin").access("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')");
    http.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll();
    http.logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}
```

всем спасибо.